# Property ɵg does not exist on type typeof @angular/http/http

Tags: angular, typescript

First time running 'ng test` I couldnt find another example of this same error anywhere

so basically I run `ng test`

then I get this error like 4 times

`ERROR in node_modules/abp-ng2-module/src/abp.module.ngfactory.ts(37,27): error TS2339: Property 'ɵg' does not exist on type 'typeof' 'typeof "C:/../angular/node_modules/@angular/http/http"`

my tsconfig looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
       "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/src/*" ],
      "@app/*": [ "./app/*" ],
      "@shared/*": [ "./shared/*" ],
      "@node_modules/*": [ "../node_modules/*" ],
      "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what else I need to show for people to help so please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I was just looking at your question prior to your modifications and it looked like you were missing a provides in your spec for the AmCharts service.

Comment: Why are you path mapping `@angular` when you're using npm or yarn and have specified node module resolution? Also type roots and paths aren't additive. You seem to be trying to resolve the same modules in redundant ways and that could well cause problems.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm using a `aspnetboilerplate` angular template, I didn't write the tsconfig so I'm not entirely sure what could be the problem

Comment: In my experience, boilerplates are usually stuffed with unnecessary and sometimes incorrect crap. Anyway, if you run the type checker from the command line, does it work?  E.g. `tsc --noEmit`

Comment: @AluanHaddad not exactly sure what you mean sorry

Comment: `tsc --noEmit --project ./tsconfig.json`

Comment: One more thing, I took a look at that boilerplate, and it looks old. Like the docs say typescript 2.0 or higher and they talk mostly about a visual studio version. You're going to have a hard time finding answers to your questions when you're using tools that are out of date.